# xpath value with condition in previous class

Tags: html, xpath

I have two div classes

```html
<div class="tooltip-series">
<span class="tooltip-series-name" style="color: rgba(255, 102, 102, 0.701961);">#1/123</span>
<span class="tooltip-series-value">68</span>
</div>
<div class="tooltip-series">
<span class="tooltip-series-name" style="color: rgba(108, 157, 198, 0.6);">#2/234</span>
<span class="tooltip-series-value">64.4</span>
</div>
```

And I need XPath which find values (68 or 64.4) according to given parameter (123 or 234).

Comment: Many things, for example

$x("//class('tooltip-series-value')//..div[contains(@class,'123')]")

$x("//*[class='tooltip-series' and contains(@class, 'tooltip-series-name'('123'))]")

$x("//*[class='tooltip-series' and contains(text('123'))]")

$x("div[contains(@class,'123')]")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your sample XML document, following XPath 1.0 expression will output `68`:

```
//span[contains(., '/123')]/following-sibling::span/text()
```

You likely need to adapt how the parameter is found, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Yes, I have the parameter, this is not the problem. 
Finally, I added //div[@class='tooltip-series']/span[contains(., '{0}')]/following-sibling::span because the parameter was in couple of places and I need to distinguish them

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat more precise way to find the element you're targeting:

```
//div[contains(concat('#', @class, '#'), '#tooltip-series#')]
     [contains(
         concat(span[contains(@class, 'tooltip-series-name')], '#'), 
         '/123#'
      )]
     /span[contains(@class, 'tooltip-series-value')]
```